# How to make set of styles to point class inside particular element

Tags: html, css

I have n number of styles in .css file.

I am using .Net MVC application

assume :

```css
.a{}
.b{}
.c{}
```

My html is like

```
<div id='blockA'> 
--- nested div containing classes a , b, c
</div>

<div id='blockB'> 
--- nested div containing classes a , b, c
</div>
```

if i want those styles to be applicable for blockA. i can do like this

```
#blockA .a{}
#blockA .b{}
#blockA .c{}
```

is there any other way to specify it for a group of styles ?

```
#blockA
{
.a{}
.b{}
.c{}
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but you can use commas to group multiple selectors and apply the same style. Example `div, #myid {color: red;}`

Comment: *if i want those styles to be applicable for blockA. i can do like this* Not if `.a` is a descendant of `#blockA`.

Comment: You could look into Less or Sass, both provide syntax similar to your latest block. Although both require the use of compilers.

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not allow nesting rules - this is a feature of CSS preprocessors like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Both allow for this:

```
#blockA {
  .a { color: blue; }
  .b { color: red; }
  .c { color: green; }
}
```

If you need to achieve the same result using native CSS only, you need to do it the following way (which is exactly what those preprocessors compile your code to):

```
#blockA .a {
  color: blue;
}

#blockA .b {
  color: red;
}

#blockA .c {
  color: green;
}
```

If the rules for `.a` `.b` and `.c` are the same:

```
#blockA {
  .a, .b, .c { color: black; }
}
```

gets compiled to

```
#blockA .a,
#blockA .b,
#blockA .c {
  color: black;
}
```

Please note that since any preprocessor will have to compile to native CSS, none of them allows you to do stuff you couldn't achieve with native CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use css preprocessors like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

then you could define like you mentioned in the .scss / .less file.

```
#blockA
{
.a{}
.b{}
.c{}
}
```